# How to know the current Spartacus version?

Tags: java, angular, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

How can I see what the current Spartacus version is. I am using Spartacus with Hybris.

Answer (score 2):

You can look for @spartacus/schematics version in your package.json

[image]

Or If you want to latest Spartacus version from SAP hybris
https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/releases

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The version is listed in `package.json`